# Trying to find expected time between calls and find the associated variance

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

The waiting time h (in hours) between each telephone call a person receives is random with the density function $f\left(h\right)=2e^{-2h}\:for\:h\ge 0$

**Question:** Find the expected time between calls and find the corresponding variance.

I am pretty much clueless on this question, I thought I could use this $V\left(a_1x_1+a_2+x_2\right)\:$
to find the variance, but for some reason, things are not adding up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $H$ is the random variable for the waiting time between each telephone call a person receives with the corresponding density function $f(h)$. Then

$$Var(H)=\mathbb E\left(H^2\right)-\left[\mathbb E\left(H\right)\right]^2=\int\limits_0^{\infty} h^2\cdot  2e^{-2h} \, dh-\left[\int\limits_0^{\infty} h\cdot  2e^{-2h} \, dh\right]^2 $$

Comment: $\left(\int _0^{\infty \:\:}x\cdot \:2e^{-2x}\right)^2$ is it suppose to be like this or like this $\int _0^{\infty \:}\:\left(x\cdot \:\:\:\:2e^{-2x}\right)^2$ for where you wrote $-\left[\int\limits_0^{\infty} h\cdot  2e^{-2h} \, dh\right]^2 $

Comment: At the first one  you calculate the integral and then square the result. That is what I´ve posted. This is $[\mathbb E(x)]^2$. since $\int_0^{\infty} x\dot f(x) \, dx=\mathbb E(x)$ At the second one you square the term and then you calculate the integral of it.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I  am not sure if $(∫)^2$ should be like that, I thought only the function was supposed to get cubed in 2 like this $((h⋅2e^{-2h})^2$

Comment: Look at the fomula $Var(X)=...-[\mathbb E(X)]^2$. So you calculate the expected value and square the result.

Comment: By the way, apply the product rule two times to calculate $Var(X)$.

Comment: $\int _0^{\infty \:}x^2\cdot 2e^{-2x}-\int _0^{\infty \:}\:\left(x\cdot \:\:\:\:2e^{-2x}\right)^2$ then this should be correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113933/discussion-between-papps-and-callculus).

Comment: No, I´ve written the opposite. $\int _0^{\infty \:}x^2\cdot 2e^{-2x} \, dx-\left(\int _0^{\infty \:}\:x\cdot \:\:\:\:2e^{-2x} \, dx \right)^2$

Comment: @Papps If you have no further question accept the answer. Thanks.